# Why use divs instead of tables for tabular data?

Tags: html

I took this from a price comparison website:

[image]

Would you expect the data in the above image to be structured in a table? I.e. with two rows and six columns. It appears to be structured as divs.

I have had a look at the HTML generated and I see that it uses Divs rather than tables.  Why is this? I realise that divs are preferred to tables for layouts, however this is not a layout; it is displaying data.

I have spent a few hours researching this and a lot of sites talk about divs and tables for layouts, however none seem to talk about divs displaying data.  Hence the question.

Comment: What are you thinking the six columns are? Two rows, sure. But I fail to see where we could draw column lines in your picture.

Comment: I definitely see this as something to build with `divs` and flexbox or grid... While it may seem to be well structured to fit a table, I don't think it displays *tabular data* in the sense the `table` element is intended for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why not use tables for layout in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html)

Comment: @IvanS95, what do you mean by "intended for"? Text?

Comment: @Silvio Mayolo, the content is not generated by a table element.  That is my point.

Comment: I mean things [like these](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/4e99b3bc00dd76ff5cf2e60371a3bcc527f00cf5/68747470733a2f2f692e696d67736166652e6f72672f643436653565312e676966) or really just [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVcNO.png)... Data that you can actually sort, filter, paginate, etc

Answer (score 2):

At one point in history, rendering tables was slower than using DIVs I believe. This may now be a relic of the past, but since a large ecosystem was then build around CSS mechanisms it probably just stuck. I am not sure that is necessarily true anymore with modern browsers. They are doing far more complex things these days other than rending a table.

Also, tables were created for tabular data display, not necessarily page formatting. If you have to render a page with a composition that cannot really be tabulated, then you have restrictions on what you can do. DIVs seem to give far more granularity for page layout.

Answer (score 2):

**Two words: Responsive Design!**

Making your DOM responsive while using a `<table>` with many columns can be a major hassle. HTML `div`s are extremely powerful DOM elements that can be configured to behave like a table on a wider viewports while being capable of adapting to smaller viewports (using media queries and other fancier display options like flexbox). For example, observe the snippet below on a wide-screen monitor and then reduce the width of the viewport. It is pretty straightforward to make the DOM responsive using media queries. Imagine the same using an HTML table. Since a table row cannot be forced to render as a column, making it responsive would be a nightmare, if not impossible!

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

@media (max-width: 1250px) {
  #container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <img src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/853168/pexels-photo-853168.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500' />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRWNjJlrLa7zz1sxYt9pabVcLkdO3rBucsFDACJRqifXknjU1xV' />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQx2AX6jE_BuRr1_Bce2isaDKwv7ZtBiG9Rlwo4VuMZNqRMkV_L' />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTg4Il-0K1k0wgK_47FURvRl9-K7sjPvK8_DefbmrOVMdxcPOcE' />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you explain why it is a major hassle? Thanks.  +1 for responsive design reference.

Comment: Would you always use divs as an alternative to tables?

Comment: Yes! Unless of course you're only going to display the tabular data on a desktop/laptop browser and not on smartphones and tablets. In that case, you might lean towards using a table.

Comment: I'd say `table` can still be used on mobile, its fine, but of course, `table` should be use to display strictly *tabular* data, literally *records* of values, not elements arranged like a table that are just arranged like that for presentation purposes.. In fact, the only part of the picture above I would *maybe* consider a `table` element is just the middle section with the percentages for balance transfers and all that

Comment: @IvanS95, say I have an image in a cell (an image only), then should I be using a div?

Comment: @w0051977 that's the thing, why would you use a table element if you are dealing with images like that? You should build the structure using divs instead and style them to look similar to a table, you are still using tables just for presentation, which you shouldn't do... you just want something that *looks* like a table

Comment: Before I accept - would you say that tables should never be used and divs should always be used.  I know about Divititis.

Comment: Well, you can live without using tables, that I can say for sure! Also, say you want to create a desktop app using Electron and want to should tabulated (non-paginated) information without worrying about making your app responsive. In that case, you may use an HTML table.